# Grails assert - verify that assertion failed in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails

Grails newbie question:

when you have `assert [condition]` in a Grails controller, how do you verify that the assertion fails from a unit test?

I'm thinking something like `shouldFail(Exception) { .. }` but I'm not sure what exception to catch.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AssertionError`.

```
shouldFail(AssertionError) {
  assert 'one' == 'two'
}
```